# How do I create a ReactiveCocoa subscriber that receives a signal only once, then unsubscribes/releases itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I'm currently registering a subscriber to a property signal like this:

```
[RACAble(self.test) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(@"signal fired!");
 }];
```

The default functionality is that it fires every single time self.test is changed, but I just want it to fire once, and then unsubscribe. Is there a "once" argument or modifier I can pass to RAC when I create this subscriber?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
[[RACAble(self.test) take:1] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"signal fired!");
}];
```

Comment: thanks, this prompted me to refactor a couple of signal generating methods into something much more sane.

Answer (score 0):

That might be helpful especially when you create nested subscriptions:

```
RACDisposable *subscription = [RACObserve(self, test) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
         NSLog(@"signal fired!");
}];
[subscription dispose];
```

Answer (score 0):

Little fix of [kamil3 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38620654/2265618):

```
__block RACDisposable *subscription = [RACObserve(self, test) subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    [subscription dispose];
    NSLog(@"signal fired!");
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also do this (if you aren't into the whole brevity thing):

```
[RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber){
   RACDisposable *inner_disposer = [RACAble(self.test) subscribeNext:^(id x){
      [subscriber sendNext:x];
      [subscriber sendComplete];
   }];
   return [RACDisposable disposableWithBlock:^{
      [inner_disposer dispose];
   }];
}];
```

Comment: There's no reason to use this over `take:1`, and it can introduce subtle bugs (like the retain cycle on `self`).